# Bootstrap Accordion Toggle On Off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap accordion written on my webpage, which works absolutely fine.
I wanted to write some added functionality, using Bootstrap Toggle ( http://www.bootstraptoggle.com ).
The main idea is that, when a checkbox is ticked, the accordion feature will work ( only one panel open at a time), and when the checkbox is unticked, we can open multiple panels at once.
Since the accordion feature works using the "data-parent" set to the "panel-group" div, I tried changing the id of the div to disable accordion, but it doesn't really work.
This is the div for the panel group.(Have 2 of them)

```
<div name="panel1" class="panel-group" id="blah">
```

Checkbox

```
<div align="center" class="checkbox">
    <input onchange="setClass(this)" id="collapse-logic" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Shrink On" data-off="Shrink Off">
</div>
```

This is the JS code on the onchange() event for my checkbox

```
function setClass(elem){
        if(elem.checked){
            document.getElementsByName("panel1")[0].id="accordion";
            document.getElementsByName("panel2")[0].id="accordion2";                
        }
        else{
            document.getElementsByName("panel1")[0].id="blah";
            document.getElementsByName("panel2")[0].id="blah2";                
        }
}
```

I figured changing the data-parent name will disable the functionality, but it doesn't quite work. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "destroy" the collapse plugin and then re-init without the parent option..

```
   // multi mode
   $('.panel-collapse').removeData('bs.collapse'); // destroy collapse
   $('.panel-collapse').collapse({parent:false});

   // single accordion mode
   $('.panel-collapse').removeData('bs.collapse'); // destroy collapse
   $('.panel-collapse').collapse({parent:'#accordion'});
```

**[Codeply Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/xhT4RQTq7L)**